# Numpy swap the values of nested columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given the following data structure is there some way I can swap the first and last column such that each row is [3, 2, 1] (I don't wish to sort them) without looping through each row?

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  ...
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  ...
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]]]
```

Comment: `a = a[..., ::-1]`. Alternatively, `np.flip(a, axis=2)`. If you're swapping BGR to RGB and back for computer vision stuff, I think it's more preferable to use built-in functions to do so, as it will be more readable (e.g. `cvtColor()` in OpenCV...) but the above options will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @alkasm! that works. I am aware of cvtColor() but in this case, I don't want that/trying to become more familar with numpy syntax.